# Getting "Optimistic concurrency failure, object has been modified." in Entity Framework 6 Identity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

When trying to update an identity from two parallel threads, I'm getting and `IdentityResult` that contains this error message: `Optimistic concurrency failure, object has been modified.`

I would like to refresh the model and retry. 
Something like this.

```
var result = await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(memberIdentity, new Claim("abc", "cde"));
if(!result.Succeeded)
{
   //reload identity or context

   //retry
   await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(memberIdentity, new Claim("abc", "cde"));
}
```

Any ideas on how I would reload the identity or the context?

Comment: did you resolve it? I'm having similar issue

Comment: Can't you just reload the  user and try again?

Comment: did you resolve it? I hava same issue when using `userManager.UpdateAsync`

Comment: that was so long ago.. can't really help you with that now.